# Какую из 4-х степеней изоляции транзакций реализует Spring-аннотация @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transaction

Собственно, сабж выше. Верно ли я вообще понимаю, что данная аннотация реализует одну из степеней защиты? Если да - какую из?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это означает что метод помеченный этой аннотацией исполняется в транзакционном окружении, а уровень изоляции задается через параметр аннотации:

```
 @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

Если уровень изоляции не указан, то используется уровень изоляции БД над которым развернут Spring